# Can I parse and export information from a web-page that has multiple links in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to parse a number of 3 to 4 diseases the clinical recommendation to follow for a project in my university.

Basically, from https://www.uspreventiveservicestaskforce.org/BrowseRec/Index/browse-
I would like to parse and export into Excel the Table Head (Name, Type, Year, Age Group) and than to populate it with the diseases, but also, more important, with the information available inside the link (Population, Recommendation, Grade).

The idea is that I do not know how to parse the information inside the links - for example, take the first link disease (Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm: Screening) that is the page with the information I need - https://www.uspreventiveservicestaskforce.org/Page/Document/UpdateSummaryFinal/abdominal-aortic-aneurysm-screening

Is Beautiful Soup the go to solution? I am a newbie to this, so any help is highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is

1. use [python-requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) to get the index page
2. use BeautifulSoup to parse the page's content and extract the urls your interested in
3. for each of those urls, use `requests` again to get "disease" page, then BeautifulSoup again to extract the data you're interested in
4. use the `csv` module to write those data into a .csv file, that can be opened by Excel (or any other similar program like OpenOffice etc).

So in pseudocode:

```
get the index content
for each disease_url in the index content:
    get the disease page content
    retrieve data from the page content
    write data to csv
```

All of those packages are [rather well documented](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree), so you shouldn't have too many issues implementing this in Python.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this and come back with a resolution.